# removing Un-styled active/selected border

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

There is a border on my selected obj that I have not specified. It appears when an item is active and selected. In the case of tabs if you click the tab you see this gold ring around the tab until you click anything else. If you start a dialog the default button gets the same treatment. I have my individual css in the fiddle minus the images but its easy to see.  I believe this is a browser thing as IE 10 only has a dashed white outline on the dialog button and not the tab but chrome has a gold ring on both in turn.

Can and how can I stop that behavior?

```
  // most basic of tab calls:
  $(function() {
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
```

the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/Pbzmr/). But this can bee seen on the theme roller pages as well.

Comment: good edit onetrickpony, I'm so used to typing that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in the CSS and you are set :)

```
:focus{outline:none;}
```

It could be a problem if the user navigating through TAB key though, as it will remove all the highlighting. Doubt anyone does it though.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be wanting to set the border to "none" in CSS.

```
border: none;
```

My bad. It is the outline

```
outline: none;
```